# arc welder app showing blank screen startup

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc

I am using Google Chrome version 64.0.3255.0 (64-bit) I installed ARC Welder extension from chrome web store. when i opened it, it shows blank window
now how to install android apps using ARC Welder?

Comment: I am not certain that ARC Welder is maintained anymore. Many Chrome OS users have access to the Play Store directly on their hardware, and AFAIK that's Google's long-term direction for Android-on-Chrome OS.

Comment: And is the android tag necessary here I think apk is better than it!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, solved it by downloading previous version (f.e. 56). You can download it from https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php